# How do I convert pixels into x coordinates of the data in ios charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

How can I convert pixels into coordinates? I want convert the translation from the viewPortHandler into the coordinate system of the data. I'm using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your question correct because there's not too much details in it. If you have coordinates of some point on chart view in view coordinate system (say `viewPoint`) and want to get coordinates of that point in internal coordinate system of chart, you can get those coordinates using `valueForTouchPoint(point:axis:)` method like this:

```
// assuming that your data is related to left yAxis
chartView.valueForTouchPoint(point: viewPoint, axis: .left)
```